# Store values into cell array during loop: Matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have tried the following code:

```
V = [0.5 0.1 0.1 0.9 0.5 0.1 0.9 0.9 0.5];
S = {'A','B','C'};
N = sqrt(numel(V));
M = reshape(V, N, N).';

for i=1:N
    for j=i+1:N
        if M(i,j)<M(j,i)
            %print(S(i),'<',S(j)) % A< B, A<C, C<B
            order1=S{i};
            order2=S{j};
            fprintf('orders:\n%s%s \n', order1,order2);
            S1(i,:)=(order1,order2) % bug is here
            % It should be the same output with S1={'AB', 'BC', 'AC'}
        else
            order1=S{i};
            order2=S{j};
            fprintf('orders:\n%s%s', order2,order1);
            S2(j,:)=(order2,order1)
        end
    end
end
```

I would like to store the values of `order1` and `order2` into the `S1` cell-array. But it seems there is a bug in my code when doing this. My loop correctly outputs `'AB', 'AC', 'BC'` to the command window, but `S1 = {'AC'; 'BC'}` at the end.

How can I get the correct `S1`, which should be the same output with `S1 = {'AB', 'BC', 'AC'}`?

Comment: Please add more context to your question. It is currently unclear in what you're trying to ask.  What does `order1` and `order2` do? What is the objective of this code?

Comment: Rewrite the line: `S1{1,:}=[order1,order2]`. The same for `S2`.

Comment: it should be S1{i,:}=[order1,order2]. Right ?

Comment: @rayryeng: I try to compare M(i,j)and M(j,i) and output the string of orders. But my code shoud output: AC , BC but no AB. It should be: S1={'AB', 'BC', 'AC'}.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues here

1. Your assignment to a cell isn't quite right, you should replace

   ```
   S1(i,:)=(order1,order2)
   ```

   with

   ```
   S1{i} = [order1, order2];
   ```

   The square brackets concatenate the characters `order1` and `order2` into one string, then the curly braces assign that string as a cell array element.
2. Your output struct is `S1 = {'AC'; 'BC'}` but your desired output (shown by the `fprintf` statements) is:

   ```
   >> orders: AB
   >> orders: AC
   >> orders: BC
   ```

   This is because `i = 1` for both cases `'AB'` and `'AC'`, so the first element in `S1` is getting overwritten! Instead, consider building up the cell by concatenation. This was shown in your [more recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446790/combine-many-cell-arrays-into-one-cell-array-matlab/43446914#43446914).

**Updated code**:

```
V = [0.5 0.1 0.1 0.9 0.5 0.1 0.9 0.9 0.5];
S = {'A','B','C'};
N = sqrt(numel(V));
M = reshape(V, N, N).';

S1 = {};  S2 = {};

for i = 1:N
    for j = i+1:N
        if M(i,j)<M(j,i)
            %print(S(i),'<',S(j)) % A< B, A<C, C<B
            order1=S{i};  order2=S{j};
            fprintf('orders:\n%s%s \n', order1,order2);
            % append item to the cell array
            S1 = [S1, {[order1,order2]}]; 
        else
            order1=S{i};  order2=S{j};
            fprintf('orders:\n%s%s', order2,order1);
            S2 = [S2, {[order2,order1]}]; 
        end
    end
end

% S1 = {'AB', 'AC', 'BC'}
```