# Combine many cell arrays into one cell array (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have 3 cell arrays :

```
c1={'a','b','c'}
c2={'a2','b2','c2'}
c3={'a3','b3','c3'}
```

How can I combine those 3 cell arrays into 1 cell array C as follows:

```
C={'a','b','c','a2','b2','c2','a3','b3','c3'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use square brackets;

```
c = [c1, c2, c3]

% c = {'a'    'b'    'c'    'a2'    'b2'    'c2'    'a3'    'b3'    'c3'}
```

This can be used when appending items to the end of a cell too,

```
d1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
d2 = [d1, {'e'}];
```

Answer (score 1):

With colon you can create comma separated lists and then concatenate them:

```
c = {c1{:}, c2{:} ,c3{:}}
```

Comment: both of the answer are nice but rahnema1 commented first so I check the for him . Thanks all !

Comment: @kgk Thanks for acceptance, although I think Wolfie's answer is more acceptable:)

Comment: ok, then I will change the accepted answer to him :). Hope it is ok for you